# How to iterate over a zipped folder?

Tags: python, file, zip

My question is how to iterate over a zipped folder, and access the files in it.
Another question is how do I get file type (something like: `".txt", ".pdf", ".zip"` and etc.)

I know how to work with `.txt` files, but not something like this.

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile("/path/blabla.zip", 'r') as first_zip:
    first_zip.printdir()
    temp = first_zip.infolist()
```

As for now I have only learned that `.printdir()` print the names and extension of the file in the zip. And `.infolist()` returns something like a list (to be honest I do not know what type it returns) with the name and file size.

Comment: What have you already researched and why it did not satisfy your needs?

Comment: A good place to start would be to look at the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) library

Comment: @PM77-1 , I have only managed to find "zipfile" library, and learnt how to print names of the files in the zip-dolfer , but i do not understand how to get the names directly and iterate over the folder in order to work with the files

Comment: @Arseniy can you share how far you have come with zipfile so far?

Comment: `[n for n in z.namelist() if n.lower().endswith('.pdf')]` will give you a list of names of the PDF files within the ZipFile instance `z`. You can then use `z.open(n)` or `z.read(n)` to get at the contents of the file with name `n`.

Comment: Here's some supplemental information on using the [`zipfile`](https://pymotw.com/3/zipfile/index.html) module.